# Firebase - Adding a value for every row

Tags: json, firebase

Let's say I have this Firebase table of myfirebase.firebaseio.com/ and in `accounts` I have this data:

```
{
  "uid:12123" : {
    "email" : "charmin@ultra.net",
    "username" : "Charmin"
  },
  "uid:253" : {
    "email" : "dejan@damjanovic.net",
    "username" : "Dejan"
  },
  "uid:353" : {
    "email" : "what@ever.net",
    "username" : "Tester"
  },
  "uid:873" : {
    "email" : "green@hand.net",
    "username" : "Green Guy"
  }
}
```

How would I add a value/key into every row `uid:12123`, `uid:253`, `uid:353`, etc... without having to do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firebase you can register an `on('child_added'` listener. This will be triggered for every existing child straight away and then for every child that is added afterwards. With that knowledge, you can update each user with:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/accounts');
ref.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.ref().update({ uid: snapshot.key() });
});
```

Be aware that we're duplicating data here, since the value you're looking for is already available as `snapshot.key()`. While duplication is often a good idea in NoSQL databases, to ensure you can read the data you need in one go, it feels wasteful here.

Note that most of these operations are covered in [Firebase's quickstart](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/quickstart.html) and all of them are certainly covered in the [programming guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/). Spending some them on both of them is well worth your time.

Comment: Another way I thought I could do it is that I do have the user do it manuallly since it will be a lot of rows. But yes, this is good. Thank you.